# Ratio test for convergence of a given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$, then applying the ratio test we get:

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}:\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}=\frac{(n+1)!\cdot n^n}{n^{n+1}\cdot n!}=\frac{(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^n}=\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) ^n\to\frac{1}{e}.$$ 
So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1 \Rightarrow $ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.
I understand the reasoning behind this example, but I did it in a different way and I would like somebody to show me where I did an error:

$$\frac{(n+1)!\cdot n^n}{n^{n+1}\cdot n!}=\frac{n!(n+1)\cdot n^n}{n^n \cdot n \cdot n!}=\frac{(n+1)}{n}=1,$$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges.

Comment: At the denominator there is $(n+1)^{n+1}$  and not $n^{n+1}$.

Comment: Your denominator should be $(n+1)^{n+1}.n!$, in case you want to use the ratio test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is only a typo while writing it down, but $a_{n+1}$ is given by $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ (as you noted earlier by yourself) but you used $\frac{(n+1)!}{\color{red}{n}^{n+1}}$ instead in your calculations. Then the ratio test is inconclusive as you obtain $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1+\frac1n=1$ (this limit does *not* approach $e$ by the way). This mistake was of course already pointed out in the comments.